# Report Viewer In VS 2010 always showing loading in ie 8

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer-8, reportviewer, report-viewer2010

when I tested small data in report viewer in vs 2010 without parameters it works fine without any problems in ie 8. 
But if there is big data with parameters it shows the loading and Never stops, But it works fine in chrome without any problem..

please any idea, or there are something to do in ie options ???
Thanks in advance!